# Conditional merge in power query in excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

In one table it is 
Column 1 GSTIN , Column 2 Involved No. , Column 3 Amt

In second table , the column is same as above

Now I m doing power query using merge , it is combining table using 1 parameter that is invoice no. but if I want to merge on the basis of 2 parameters that is GSTIN and Invoice No. using power query.
Will it be possible using power query based on 2 parameters

Comment: yes  in the merge dialog, just click another set of columns from top and bottom

Comment: I appreciate. Thanks a lots.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  When you merge the tables, hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button and select multiple columns in the first table, then do the same in the 2nd table.  Make sure you select the columns in the same order for both tables.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate. Thanks a lots